# applying lm or lsfit on matrix vs matrix

Tags: r

How do I use lm (or lsfit) to fit column 1 of a matrix A with column 1 of matrix B. Then column 2 of matrix A with column 2 of matrix B and so on. The matrices may have NAs

Comment: Please include some sample data and explain clearly what you'd like the output to be.

Answer (score 1):

If you coerce to data.frame then they can be processed as a series of lists with mapply:

```
> mapply(function(x,y) lm(y~x), as.data.frame(m1) , as.data.frame(m2) )
              V1         V2         V3        
coefficients  Numeric,2  Numeric,2  Numeric,2 
residuals     Numeric,4  Numeric,4  Numeric,4 
effects       Numeric,4  Numeric,4  Numeric,4 
rank          2          2          2         
fitted.values Numeric,4  Numeric,4  Numeric,4 
assign        Integer,2  Integer,2  Integer,2 
qr            List,5     List,5     List,5    
df.residual   2          2          2         
xlevels       List,0     List,0     List,0    
call          Expression Expression Expression
terms         Expression Expression Expression
model         List,2     List,2     List,2    

> ?lsfit
> mapply(function(x,y) lsfit(y,x), as.data.frame(m1) , as.data.frame(m2) )
             V1        V2        V3       
coefficients Numeric,2 Numeric,2 Numeric,2
residuals    Numeric,4 Numeric,4 Numeric,4
intercept    TRUE      TRUE      TRUE     
qr           List,6    List,6    List,6
```